# Django migrate attempts to connect to non-default database

Tags: python, mysql, django

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases):

> The migrate management command operates on one database at a time. By default, it operates on the default database, but by providing the --database option, you can tell it to synchronize a different database.

My Django application has the following database configuration in my local development environment:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'external_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myexternaldb',
        'USER': 'myexternaluser',
        'PASSWORD': 'myexternalpassword',
        'HOST': '10.10.10.10',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

I only have one table in the "external_db" database, and I treat it as read-only (in fact, the user only has read permissions). When I try to migrate a table in my default database, I get the following error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.10.10.10' (10060)")

Why is the migrate operation trying to connect to this external database when the documentation expressly indicates that it only works on the *default* database by default? Is this a Django bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any management command is executed, Django will [run system checks](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d65b0f72de8d35617fe0554ddabc950c7f323eef/django/core/management/base.py#L343-L344) on your whole project.

The [core system checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/checks/#core-system-checks) performed by Django include several database checks. In your case, the database is not available, hence the failure. The migration itself will be performed on the database you have selected, but in order for the checks to pass, the other databases need to be accessible by Django.

If that particular database is not available locally then the normal approach would be to have a local settings file that overrides the `DATABASES` setting and removes that key.